# Remove an Application from Control Panel?

Tags: windows, uninstall

Any Windows tool available to remove an application from Control Panel's "Add or Delete Programs"? For example I have an application listed in the Control Panel. I know I can remove it from disk and there is no need to clean it from reg or any other places. However, the app is still in the Control Panel's "Add or Delete Programs" list.

I think that there is Windows reg setting for this. Not sure what tool is available to remove it? The reason I ask this question is that I want to do it in an automation way instead of manual way.

The Windows is XP platform.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Ccleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) both to remove programs and to clear them from the registry. It comes with a registry error finder (and fixer) so it should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

All items displayed in "Add or remove programs" are stored in the registry. Take a look at the following key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Each key (folder) has a number of values that relate to how it is displayed in the Control Panel applet. Remove it from here, and it won't show up on the list.

When looking through the keys, look for the `UninstallString` value. It should point to a location on the drive, not MsiExec.exe. From what I've seen, the ones that point to Msiexec are redundant and don't always need to be removed. It depends on the software in question.

Comment: OK. All the items there are makred by GUID keys. I think they varies on machines.

Comment: GUID don't change between machines. They are used to identify programs and set by the software vendor. If you scroll down the list, past the GUID's, you will find things identified by name. The GUID's are usually sub components of other things installed. for example, Adobe CS3 has one main entry with a name and a bunch of keys for the dozen or so components.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310750) about this problem. It requires modification of the registry.

You can also use a tool for this, like [**Add/Remove Manager**](http://www.singerscreations.com/Add-Remove-Manager.asp):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) will scan your registry/hard drive for left behind keys and files